# Poor performance with DrawText on Win7 x64

Tags: c++, windows, performance, mfc

I noticed in an MFC application I'm developing that while dragging the scroll bar to smoothly scroll down the document, the framerate drops to choppy levels when a block containing about a paragraph of text is on screen, but silky smooth when it's offscreen.  Investigating the performance, I found the single `CDC::DrawText` call for the paragraph of text responsible.  This is in an optimised release build.

I used `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get a high-resolution measurement of *just* the DrawText call, like this:

```
QueryPerformanceCounter(...);
pDC->DrawText(some_cstring, some_crect, DT_WORDBREAK);
QueryPerformanceCounter(...);
```

The text is unicode, lorem-ipsum style filler, 865 characters long and wraps over 7-and-a-bit lines given the rectangle and font (Segoe UI, `lfHeight` = -12, a standard body text size).  From my measurements, that call *alone* takes on average 7.5 ms, with the odd peak at 21ms.  (Note to keep up with a 60Hz monitor you get about 16ms to render each update.)

I tried making some changes to improve the performance:

- Removing the `DT_WORDBREAK` improves performance to about 1ms (about 7 times faster), but given only one line of text is making it to the screen, and there were just over 7 lines with word breaking, this seems to suggest to me the bottleneck is elsewhere.
- I was drawing text in transparent mode (`SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT)`).  So I tried opaque mode with a solid background fill.  No improvement.
- I thought ClearType rendering might be to blame.  I changed the font `lfQuality` from `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY` to `NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY`.  It looked like crap with sharp edges and all, and no improvement.
- As per a comment suggestion, I was using a CMemDC, but I got rid of it and did direct drawing.  It flickered like mad, and no improvement.

This is running on a Windows 7 64-bit laptop with an Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 @ 2.26 GHz and 4 GB RAM - I don't think it counts as a slow system.

I'm calling DrawText() every time it draws and this obviously hammers the performance with such a slow function, especially if several of those text-blocks are visible at once.  It's enough to make the experience feel sluggish.  However, Firefox can render a page like this one in ClearType with much more text, and seems to cope just fine.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I get around the poor performance of an actual DrawText call?

Comment: What happens if you change hardware acceleration?

Comment: Think the way to use old-school GDI (which I presume is used internally by MFC) on Win7 simply is not good. My advice is to turn onto GDI+ way. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535991(v=VS.85).aspx). You could try and tell us results.

Comment: Seen this? http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2009/02/15/slow-drawtext-performance-in-vista-and-windows-7-please-comment/

Comment: @Keynslug I have serious doubts that GDI+ would be better, because that one is completely implemented in software and has shown time and again, that its slow as hell. My advice would be more to look into Direct2D. That might be better.

Comment: @jdv: Martin's Blog seems to say it's using the DT_CALCRECT which doesn't actually render anything.

Comment: Do you get different results if you render to a memory DC?

Comment: @Mark Ransom - this was originally measured with rendering to a memory DC, but I rendered without it instead and couldn't measure a difference either (plus it flickered like mad).

Comment: As @Christopher says, on Win7/Vista, Direct2D/DirectWrite are much better candidates performance-wise than GDI+.

Comment: Why are you trying to render the string every frame? The memory DC suggestion means render the text ONCE to a memory DC, then blit that once per frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drawing the text at every refresh is wasteful. Use *double buffering*, that is, draw in an offscreen bitmap and just blit it to the screen. Then, for scrolling, just copy most of the bitmap up or down or sideways as necessary, then draw only the invalidated area (before blitting the result to the screen).

If even that turns out to be too slow, keep also the drawn text in an off-screen bitmap, and blit instead of draw.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

According to [this german blogpost](http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2009/07/11/ausloesung-drawtext-unter-vista-gegenueber-xp-um-bis-zu-faktor-50-langsamer/), the issue has to do with support for asian language fonts. If you enable those in XP you get the same perf hit. In Vista/7, they are default enabled and you can't turn them off.

EDIT: Just maybe, using a different font might help.. (one that does not contain asian characters).

Comment: The blog post seems to refer to using the DT_CALCRECT flag, which doesn't actually render any text - I'm talking about the rendering.  FYI it seems about 7 times faster when I use the DT_CALCRECT - so, as expected, rendering is a lot slower than calculating extent.  Also, I would prefer if I could keep the best international support possible!

Comment: @AshelysBrain: Yeah, the scenario is different. But you can easily  test if the root cause is the same. If you enable these two checkboxes on your XP machine, and run your test code, what does it do with the performance?

Answer (score 2):

Users can't read text at 7 lines in 7 milliseconds, so the call itself is fast enough.

The 60 Hz refresh rate of the monitor is entirely irrelevant. You don't need to re-render the same text for every frame. The videocard will happily send the same pixels to the screen again.

So, I thibk you have another problem. Are you perhaps wondering about scrolling text? Please ask about the problem you really have, instead of assuming DrawText is the culprit.

Comment: In the question I'm talking about the performance while dragging the scroll bar, so it is continuously re-drawing the text, ideally at the refresh rate, to smoothly display the scrolling document.

Comment: Ah, right. I had a feeling you had an XY problem. So, yes, `DrawText` is in fact fast enough. But you shouldn't rerender the text just because it now needs to be a few pixels lower on the screen. Re-using the (unmodified!) CMemDC at a different offset, and adding an extra CMemDC for the newly visible  part should do the trick. This comment is a bit small to cover all details.

Answer (score 1):

In order to break the text on word breaks, DrawText needs to repeatedly try to get the width of a block of text to see if it will fit, then take the remainder and do it over. It will need to do this at every call. If your text is unchanging, this is an unnecessary overhead. As a workaround, you could measure the text yourself and insert temporary line breaks and remove the DT_WORDBREAK flag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Direct2D/DirectWrite?

Anyway it should work better if you just draw the text once to its own mem dc and blit that over to whatever dc you want it painted on with each iteration.