# How to force GetTextExtentPoint32 to take into account kerning?

Tags: winapi, fonts, gdi+, typography

I've got an application which is using GDI+ and calling `DrawTextExW` to draw text to the screen. I'm also trying to position a flashing carat at the edit point. I'm calculating the position of the carat using `GetTextExtentPoint32W`. This works perfectly with monospaced fonts, but using something like Helvetica, if I encounter a character pair which has kerning (i.e. "Yo" "To", etc.) the values I get back from GetTextExtentPoint32W are off, and continue to get farther and farther off the more of these characters I include. As you can see in the screenshot below the carat and the highlighted text are positioned as if there were no kerning:

[image: Carat and highlight position off due to kerning]

I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32w) and saw this:

> Because some devices kern characters, the sum of the extents of the characters in a string may not be equal to the extent of the string.

Unfortunately that doesn't really clear things up. Is it saying that if I were to sum up the extents of each individual character I would get a different number than what `GetTextExtentPoint32W` returns, or that `GetTextExtentPoint32W` is summing up the characters and so you shouldn't expect it to be accurate to what's drawn on the screen? What constitutes a "device" in this context?

At this point I'd be happy to either disable kerning in `DrawTextExW` or figure out how to make `GetTextExtentPoint32W` consider kerning if that's possible.

Comment: Can I suggest you switch from GDI+ to DWrite?

Comment: Do not mix `GetTextExtentPoint32` with `DrawTextEx`. For `DrawTextEx` use `DT_CALCRECT` and measure from text start.

Comment: @PeterConstable Unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: @DanielSęk I'll give that a try. Is there a speed penalty to doing DrawTextEx with `DT_CALCRECT`? When text is scrolled or to determine if text needs to be scrolled `GetTextExtentPoint32` gets called once per character until an offset in the "viewport" is found. Imagine a string 1000 characters long scrolled almost all the way to the end, in the worst case it might need to be called 900 times to determine what is first visible character in the string.

Comment: I think this may indeed cause unnecessary overhead, maybe you need to measure the text yourself. Refer to: [Poor performance with DrawText on Win7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280783/poor-performance-with-drawtext-on-win7-x64)